# Sats stuck in "pending" after lightning channel force closure

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, ln-closing-channels

I had a [lightning channel](https://amboss.space/edge/767098x1406x1) force close because the other node went offline. Its now been 24 days yet the on chain sats are still stuck in "Pending" status and can't be spent.  [This](https://mempool.space/tx/fe139c62a71dfc82e2f0ca64de5fd199d73c867acf7db9bfe6a818ebcf269878) is the closing tx and the 834,777 sats are seen in the UTXO. I'd like to learn what is happening here.

You can see from the Thunderhub screenshot below that 24 days ago 834,777 sats were sent (this [tx](https://mempool.space/address/bc1p5m89hqmtqh47takw7d23e0mp6jr33sf6jgf8mapuhltkl5avg6dqwntkfs)) during the force close. Additionally there was another 147 sats which i dont know what it was which has not been confirmed. These are showing up as a deposit as well but the [tx for the 147](https://mempool.space/tx/46f1fe6431e5c7ef2fc7c9b513871c64571b2fdf10862ab62fdbb55e21e83a61) not confirmed or even broadcast to the network.
[image]

The lightning node wallet shows the 834,777 and the 147 deposit as well:
[image]

Lastly, you can see in Thunderhub dashboard that there are a total of the sum of the two as "pending".
[image]

Can anyone explain what is going on here? What is thunderhub reading onchain that tells it those sats are in "Pending" state vs others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the same issue as described [here](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/discussions/7420). Publishing the tx from my umbrel node with the below fixed it:

```
./umbrel/scripts/app compose lightning exec lnd lncli wallet publishtx <TX>
```